# How to combine two json properties into one array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json data like this:

```
var data = [{
    "RM_Name": "Cloud Strife",
    "Division": "Avalanche",
    "RM_Phone": "No Phone",
    "RC_Name": "No RM",
    "RC_Phone": "No Phone",
    "States_Covered": "Midgar,Nibelheim"
}, {
    "RM_Name": "Clint Eastwood",
    "Division": "Hollywood",
    "RM_Phone": "No Phone",
    "RC_Name": "No RC",
    "RC_Phone": "No Phone",
    "States_Covered": "Gran Torino"
}, {
    "RM_Name": "Barret Wallace",
    "Division": "Avalanche",
    "RM_Phone": "No Phone",
    "RC_Name": "Barry Allen",
    "RC_Phone": "No Phone",
    "States_Covered": "North Corel"
}, {
    "RM_Name": "Tifa Lockheart",
    "Division": "Avalanche",
    "RM_Phone": "No Phone",
    "RC_Name": "Aeris Gainsborough",
    "RC_Phone": "No Phone",
    "States_Covered": "Sector 7"
}];
```

Now I want to create a new array consist of RM_Name and RC_Name like this so the output would be like this:

```
[Cloud Strife,Clint Eastwood,Barret Wallace,Barry Allen,Tifa Lockheart,Aeris Gainsborough]
```

How can I do that? I have tried using `$.merge()`. But I think the output is wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your example does not include the `No RM` and `No RC` entries, should these be ignored?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes just ignore it i just need to see how to combine both properties :)

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate JSON. Try this:

```
var dataArray = [];
$.each(data, function(i, v){
       dataArray.push(v.RM_Name);
       if(v.RC_Name !="No RC")
       dataArray.push(v.RC_Name);
});
console.log(dataArray);
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/G8JDz/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Doing it without jQuery and ignoring `No RC` and `No RM`.

<kbd>**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfZm4/)**</kbd>

```
var result = [];
for(var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; ++i)
{
    if(data[i].RM_Name !== 'No RM')
       result.push(data[i].RM_Name);
    if(data[i].RC_Name !== 'No RC')
       result.push(data[i].RC_Name);
}
console.log(result);
```

What this does is:

- loop over the data array
- if the `RC_Name` is different than 'No RC' push it in the array
- if the `RM_name` is different than 'No RM' push it in the array
- output the array

Answer (score 2):

Functional options (No Jquery) ~ Both IE9+ only without poly-fill.

```
var ar = data.reduce(function(previous, current)
{ 
    previous.push(current.RM_Name, current.RC_Name);  
    return previous;
}, []);
```

or (although not overly readable)

```
var ar = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], data.map(function(row){ 
    return [row.RM_Name, row.RC_Name]; 
}));
```

Comment: `reduce` is kinda of new, not supported in older browsers without polyfill. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @JoshMc Same refers to `Array.prototype.map` as well.

Comment: Get so used to including a polyfill, you forget which ones are for what browsers ^^.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>***[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyqNY/)***</kbd>
*jQuery*

```
var toShow = new Array();
$.each(data,function(i,item){
    toShow.push(item.RM_Name);
    if(item.RC_Name !="No RC")
        toShow.push(item.RC_Name);
});
```

*It would even ignore each `"RC_Name":"No RC"`*

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

Use `.each()` in jquery

```
var name = [];
$.each(data, function( index, value ) {
        name.push(value.RM_Name);
        if(value.RC_Name !="No RC")
        name.push(value.RC_Name);  
});

console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution with `$.map` and `$.grep`:

```
[].concat.apply($.map(data, function(o) {
    return $.grep([o.RM_Name, o.RC_Name], function(v) {
        return v !== 'No RM' && v !== 'No RC';
    });
}));
```

You may omit the `$.grep` part if you don't need to filter properties by value:

```
[].concat.apply($.map(data, function(o) {
    return [o.RM_Name, o.RC_Name];
}));
```